# Get all the start and the end dates of weeks of a year starting 2022 in moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-range

I want to get all the start and the end dates of weeks of a year starting 2022 in moment in YYYY-MM-DD (mysql) format.

I want the end result to look something like this:

```
[
    ['2022-01-04', '2022-01-10'],
    ['2022-01-11', '2022-01-17'],
    ['2022-01-18', '2022-01-24'],
    // ...
    ['2022-12-24', '2023-01-01'],
    ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-08'],
    // ...
    ['2023-12-25', '2024-01-01'],
    // ...
    // Until the end of 2026
];
```

EDIT 1:
I tried the code below but it's failing:

```
const moment = require('moment');

const dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
const dateToStart = '2022-04-11';
const dateToEnd = '2030-12-29';

function getWeeks() {
    const weeks = [];
    let currentDate = '2022-04-11';

    while (true) {

        if (currentDate === dateToStart) {
            weeks.push([dateToStart, moment(dateToStart, dateFormat).add(6, 'days').format(dateFormat)]);
        } else {
            weeks.push([
                moment(currentDate, dateFormat).add(1, 'days').format(dateFormat),
                moment(currentDate, dateFormat).add(6, 'days').format(dateFormat),
            ]);
        }
        currentDate = moment(dateToStart).add(6, 'days').format(dateFormat);

        if (currentDate === dateToEnd) break;
    }

    return weeks;
}
```

Comment: You should at least show us that you made an attempt to figure this out for yourself.

Comment: @phuzi I'm not much familiar with moment

Comment: @phuzi check my edit please, thanks. Would also appreciate it if you could remove the -1 and close request.

Comment: you don't say what's not working, or why it is not working.  put in some console.log() and trace what it is doing - step thru it to debug.  additionally moment is very powerful - e.g. moment().startOf('week') might be something you could use, a.o. methods;

Comment: `[ ['2022-01-04', '2022-01-10'], ['2022-01-11', '2022-01-17'], ...]` <-- seems like a rather straight-forward pattern here. `[ ["week-start-date-of-year", "+6 days  to curr-elt index-0"], ["+1 day to prev-elt index-1", "+6 days to curr-elt index-0"], ....]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Momentjs provide some really usefull functions to get the desired output.

1. Create 2 moment objects, the start and end
2. Loop, while end `isAfter` start
3. Use `.startOf('isoWeek')` and `.endOf('isoWeek')` to get the range of a week
4. Append that to an array
5. Set the start moment object 1 week forward: `.add(1, 'week')`

---

This example should get you started, note that I've lowered the `dateToEnd`.

```js
const dateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
const dateToStart = '2022-04-01';
const dateToEnd = '2023-12-29';

let weeks = [];
let momsrt = moment.utc(dateToStart, dateFormat);
let momend = moment.utc(dateToEnd, dateFormat);

while (momend.isAfter(momsrt)) {
    weeks.push([
        momsrt.startOf('isoWeek').format(dateFormat),
        momsrt.endOf('isoWeek').format(dateFormat)
    ]);
    momsrt.add(1, 'week');
}

console.log(weeks);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.32/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Foot Note:**

Please see [momentjs Project status](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

TL:DR; Don't use it for new projects, there are way better alternatives.

Comment: This worked with some tweaks, thank you. I just needed the dates so I could insert them into MySQL.